# Algorithm for recovering sparse vector x from Ax - Restricted Isometry Property

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I encountered this problem and can't figure out how to do it. Help will be appreciated!
I'm pretty sure that the distribution of matrices need to satisfy the Restricted Isometry Property, but afterwards I don't know how to recover the vector:

Assume that x is s-sparse, for a constant s, which we set as s = 60
for convenience.

Find the best parameter k (you can use O()-notation) and a distribution of matrices A of size k×n, together with an efficient ‘recovery algorithm’, such that both of the
following two properties hold:

```
(a) With probability at least 0.99, for all s-sparse vectors x ∈ R
    n with coefficients in {−1, 0, 1}, the recovery algorithm returns x upon input Ax, and
(b) For all non s-sparse vectors x with coefficients in {−1, 0, 1}, with
    probability at least 0.99, the algorithm returns ‘FAIL’.
```

Note 1: The order of the quantifiers in (a) and (b) is reversed. In [(a)] you have
‘with prob.... for all’ and in[(b) you have ‘for all...with prob’.

Note 2: The requirement of the coefficients being in {−1, 0, 1} can be removed, and a
stronger statement can be made for integer coefficients.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a purely mathematical exercise (homework assignment)?  Or are you working with a specific programming language and sparse package?

Comment: Purely mathematical